Control Access in ArgoCD
I have the RedHat GitOps Operator runnung that provides access to ArgoCD.
Login to ArgoCD works via a OICD Provider.
I now want to control visibility of Applications and ApplicationSets inside ArgoCD the same way the user has access in OpenShift.
Our users have AD groups assigned, e.g., AR-Project-xyz-admin or similar. Via these groups, the user now only has access to the project/namespace xyz.
We create the AppProject and the ApplicationSet as illustrated below:
local namespace = std.extVar("projectPrefix") + "-" + std.extVar("projectName");

kind: 'AppProject',
apiVersion: 'argoproj.io/v1alpha1',
metadata: {
    name: namespace,
    namespace: 'openshift-gitops',
},
spec: {
    description: 'Project to manage ' + std.extVar("displayName") + ' applications.',
    destinations: [
    {
        name: 'in-cluster',
        server: 'https://kubernetes.default.svc',
        namespace: namespace,
    },
    {
        name: 'in-cluster',
        server: 'https://kubernetes.default.svc',
        namespace: namespace + '-*',
    },
    ],
 ...

apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: ApplicationSet
metadata:
  name: openshift-projects
spec:
  goTemplate: true
  generators:
 ...

For me now it is unclear, how I can control that the user with AR-Project-xyz-admin can only see these AppProjects and the ApplicationSet have the name set to xyz.
Many thanks in advance for your support.
